# Connect between containers in a network in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have setup my docker-compose files to connect to an external network as follows:

```
networks:
  backend:
    external:
      name: app-network
```

And then adding the network to each container like

```
    networks:
      - backend
```

I'm also doing this for my nginx container. When I run `wget http://localhost:8004/ -q -O -` it successfully gives back the source code. However when I run it from one of the containers in the network, it's not getting the source code.

The containers seem to be successfully added to the network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "app-network",
        "Id": "5c5ed53b3837e1c784b9b7f7ac9dd6ff1786e52159e33194ed986ec63b3fcd42",
        "Created": "2021-02-16T16:41:49.068787748+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.16.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.16.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "54357d1bfde9c7dcfc9ca4ae8804ec14a844fb047fefa22bfdafc15a4b8a07bc": {
                "Name": "elasticsearch",
                "EndpointID": "42f420c4976e116562945ad27e0a57785246e036159d75b868575ccfb8ab0b08",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:06",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.6/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5ccfad66a3995761d4b86fa9007dbe7a8e53b83c8fe65477c851944feba127da": {
                "Name": "vue-storefront-api_redis_1",
                "EndpointID": "47d48c065b1e18fb748da7eea32197f0b8984923930f1938599061c93c5f01f9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:05",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.5/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "90e4943fecd7145e01874a1dbbfe483105b01bf7b24dc90ec7244d8526959d82": {
                "Name": "02-store_nginx_1",
                "EndpointID": "4a9c586d0ccb97a4b7b2c7d58c7e24da1062b1dcedbdb0d76e42f3395f91c55c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:04",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.4/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "936e3994f39bee0e530fa6abbb832e646b7254d068c49f0a3df40675f7ff5e76": {
                "Name": "vue-storefront-api_kibana_1",
                "EndpointID": "425be601669607429c334f075a164fa02c572961912271cd82e59d2fbbcc55b7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:07",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.7/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "cb85c99c7b65c21605b29cb0f0b927985c69489073907935d96429763374d308": {
                "Name": "vue-storefront-api_app_1",
                "EndpointID": "ccc70ec9a3ea48057fa0646a49da2b9765224c3b4c7815fab79873fa8b368b22",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:08",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.8/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e9441aa78ca9f741ea4813f86f43c27438126c91cafb9897e3aac26d85622b3e": {
                "Name": "02-store_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "0864f74cf585ed1068926a42e2419cdf3235f6d831f91061a45b157cab7deee3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e9bfb008fe599a46c319df8193f8acbf6fdd8e0cfafd822334c5e18b7372d9b9": {
                "Name": "02-store_php_1",
                "EndpointID": "5fa6812af20bbac021a072f32b972dd31005e49f2f3028efc473a63be688d0e3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What URL are you using to make a call from one container to another?  `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container" and not another one, even if they're on the same network.

Comment: Good question @DavidMaze I've tried `http://nginx/`, `http://backend/` and indeed localhost as well. However nginx and backend also seem to map to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Some additional information: I can ping nginx from inside the container, however if I wget I get the following:
/var/www # wget nginx
Connecting to nginx (192.168.16.8:80)
Connecting to website.local:8004 (127.0.0.1:8004)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

Comment: What's the `website.local` name?  A [mcve] showing the entire setup would be very helpful.

Comment: In the end it turned out that the script would redirect to website.local.. I solved it by giving the nginx container a fixed ipv4 so I could redirect there instead. Thanks for thinking with me!